# Trying to display the specific id on the edit page

Tags: javascript, java, html

I am trying to display the ticket name for the selected ticket on the edit page but am confused about how to display it on the UI.

code JS:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoDAe.png)

code HTML:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxFFB.png)

list ticket page:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIyfZ.png)

edit page:

Note: Here, the id name and status should show
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8itnn.png)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get truly how your code is working but I think the main problem you are facing is having the same id for different HTML elements (same id for input and label, same id for select and label).

```
  <!-- this is okey -->  
  <label for="firstInput" >First input</label>
  <input id="firstInput">
  <!-- this isnt okey , same id for input and label --> 
  <label for="secondInput" id="secondInput" >Second input</label>
  <input id="secondInput">
```

[You can find an example here](https://jsfiddle.net/da3az/qgmofrLk/48/)

Hope that will solve your problem

Comment: Hello Chakib, thanks a lot for spent your valuable time to responded to my query, but actually my need is when I click the edit button from the tickets list page it should show the clicked(selected) ticket name and its status on the edit page placeholder, can you please help me on this?

Comment: Hey , As I said I didn't get how this code really works, if you want to get an element text to be as placeholder for an input you to call the element.innerText and set it to input.value .
YOU CAN go see the link which I submitted on the solution, I have added an example on how to do so.